# How to detect at telegram bot script's end that preview was ON when a URL in message was sent by a user in a group

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am Developing a telegram bot. Bot is able to receive messages sent by users in a group. Users send URLs in my group and bot script can detect through entity object whether it is a URL or not.

My objective is to detect, when a user send a URL with preview ON.

Is there any possible way to detect it at my bot script?

Comment: I am sorry, But I am not aware of all the things of stackoverflow. I have accepted that answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, bots can't get this type of data :(

Here have a solution you might interested, if your bot have admin, you can just [restrict](https://tg.sean.taipei/payload.php?restrictChatMember-44d34f8d) **every users** with all permission but `can_add_web_page_previews`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I check it and let you know.

Comment: It worked. It requires to update the group to supergroup however once this restriction was set, Previews were disappeared. Thanks a lot for your help.